# React Native Hook problem [ useNavigation ]

Tags: react-native, hook

I am writing applications with React Native. I am using typescript. I am using Hook and getting an error in the application. When I searched, Hook is valid as of React-Native version 0.59.0 but I'm having trouble.

How can I solve it?

Hook Issue App

http://prnt.sc/vvkotk

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React from "react";
import { Dimensions, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Box, Header, Text } from "../../components";
import { useTheme } from "../../components/Theme";

const Drawer = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const theme = useTheme();
    return (
        <Box flex={1}>
            <Box flex={0.2} backgroundColor="white">
                <Box 
                position="absolute" 
                top={0} 
                left={0} 
                right={0} 
                bottom={0} 
                borderBottomRightRadius="xl" 
                backgroundColor="secondary"
                >
```

Comment: I dont see any hook used here. Where are you using your hooks ?

Comment: The hook useNavigation()...
What error are you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it doesn't recognise your custom useTheme hook. Please make sure the filename starts with `use` so `useTheme.tsx` of `useTheme.jsx`. Check the filename of your Drawer component as well to be sure. It should contain `.jsx` or `.tsx`.